# Converter objeto para String?

Tags: java, string, conversão-de-tipo

Qual é a melhor forma de converter um objeto para uma variável do tipo `int`? Ou não existe essa conversão?

Exemplo:

```
        if (teste == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            int linha = tblPessoa.getSelectedRow();

            // Aqui o objeto não pode ser convertido em string.
            int codigo = Integer.parseInt(tblPessoa.getModel().getValueAt(linha, 0));
            pessoaController.excluir(Integer.valueOf(codigo));
    }
```

Comment: Você quer saber a conversão do que para que? `String` para `int`? Se concentre em uma coisa na pergunta.

Comment: É como o @bigown disse, seja objetivo em sua pergunta.

Comment: Conversão de objeto para tipos primitivos e não conversão de tipo primitivos para tipo primitivos.

Comment: Fiz a edição e agora to esperando a respostas @bigown.

Comment: @IgorContini Você sabe o tipo do objeto? Ou ele pode ser de qualquer tipo? Se pode ser de qualquer tipo, porque?

Comment: Consegui converter o objeto tblPessoa que é a tabela pessoa colocando uma String do lado esquerdo na frente da tblPessoa.

Comment: @IgorContini A resposta que foi dada logo abaixo funciona também.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiro é preciso diferenciar **conversão**, que consiste em transformar um tipo de dado em outro, de um **cast**, que consiste em acessar um objeto como um tipo mais específico do que a referência atual permite.

## Conversão

Converter um tipo de valor em outro exige uma rotina que faça o processamento dos bytes ou caracteres.

Esta resposta considera que a conversão entre número e texto é feita na base 10.

### Converter Inteiro para String

Uma variável do tipo `Integer`

```
String str = myInteger.toString();
```

Inteiro primitivo:

```
String str = Integer.toString(123, 10); //base 10
```

### Converter String para Inteiro

O comando é simples:

```
Integer inteiro = Integer.valueOf("1");
```

Ou se quiser o valor primitivo:

```
int inteiro = Integer.parseInt("1");
```

O problema é que se a String for digitada ou lida de alguma fonte externa, ela pode não conter um número válido. Por isso, é importante **sempre** tratar a exceção `NumberFormatException`, assim:

```
try {
    int inteiro = Integer.parseInt(stringDuvidosa);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    //log, mensagem de erro, etc.
}
```

## Cast

Se você tem um objeto de um tipo específico referenciado como um tipo genérico, você pode fazer um *cast* para acessá-lo novamente como o tipo específico.

Exemplo:

```
Object objeto = Integer.valueOf(1);
Integer inteiro = (Integer) objeto;
```

No exemplo acima:

1. Um objeto do tipo `Integer` é criado
2. Ele é armazenado numa variável do tipo `Object`
3. O *cast* `(Integer)` faz com que a variável do tipo `Object` possa ser atribuída para uma variável do tipo `Integer`

Note que o *cast* não modifica o objeto em nenhum aspecto, apenas a forma como ele é referenciado.

Se o tipo real do objeto não fosse compatível com `Integer` uma exceção `ClassCastException` seria lançada em tempo de execução. Por isso é sempre bom verificar se o *cast* será possível. Exemplo:

```
Object objeto = ...
if (objeto instanceof Integer) {
    Integer inteiro = (Integer) objeto;
} else {
    //log, erro, etc.
}
```

Nesse caso, não é preciso tratar `ClassCastException` com `try/catch`, porque `instanceof` garante que isso não ocorrerá.

Muitas IDEs, tal como o Eclipse, emitirão um aviso (*warning*) se encontrarem um *cast* sem um `instanceof` antes.

Comment: Muito boa a explicação! Valeu e obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Olá,

você pode fazer um *casting* passando para o tipo esperado, mas é bom ter certeza que o objeto é do tipo correto.

```
int i = (Integer) object;
```

Font: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661413/how-to-cast-an-object-to-an-int-in-java)

Comment: Para enriquecer um pouco mais a resposta, acredito que um bloco com `try`  `catch` para tratar uma possível exceção lançada seria uma boa aposta.

Comment: Deu certo aqui e valeu!

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar o `String.valueOf(int)`

Por exemplo:

```
int par = 2;
String dois = String.valueOf(par);
```

Comment: Acredito que o OP esteja buscando a operação contrária (Objeto para `int`), veja que o Objeto não necessáriamente é uma `String`.