# Conversão de Inteiro para String

Tags: c#, string, conversão-de-tipo, int

Estou criando um sistema de lanchonete.
Criei o sistema de login e está funcionando, quando fui criar uma página para criar os logins, estou com dificuldades em converter o Nível de `int` para `string` - o **`txtNivel.Text`** não sai do vermelho, seguem os códigos:

```
public int Codigo = 0;

private void Gravar(string Login, string Senha, int Nivel, string InfAdicionais)
{
    try
    {
        Dados objDados = new Dados();
        objDados.Gravar(Login, Senha, Nivel, InfAdicionais);

        txtLogin.Clear();
        txtSenha.Clear();
        txtNivel.Clear();
        txtInfAdicinais.Clear();

        string menssagem = "Seus dados foram gravados com sucesso.";

        MessageBox.Show(menssagem);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro: " + ex.Message);
    }
}

private void btn_Adicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLogin.Text) &&
           !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSenha.Text) &&
           !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNivel.Text))
            Gravar(txtLogin.Text, txtSenha.Text, txtNivel.Text**, txtInfAdicinais.Text);
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro");
    }
}
```

Dados:

```
//Usuarios

public class Usuarios

{
    public int IdUsuario { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public int Nivel { get; set; }
    public string InfAdicionais { get; set; }
}

public void Gravar(string Login, string Senha, int Nivel, string InfAdicionais)
{
    using (SqlConnection objConexao = new SqlConnection(strConexao))
    {
        using (SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(strInsert, objConexao))
        {
            objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login", Login);
            objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Senha", Senha);
            objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nivel", Nivel);
            objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InfAdicionais", InfAdicionais);

            objConexao.Open();

            objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            objConexao.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nivel", Nivel.ToString());

Comment: Pode ser um pouco mais especifico onde coloco isso e por que? sou novo no assunto

Comment: a bom ... Gravar(txtLogin.Text, txtSenha.Text, Int32.Parse( txtNivel.Text), txtInfAdicinais.Text);

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212553/necessito-converter-uma-string-em-int-dentro-de-uma-hql

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93866/converter-objeto-para-string/93870#93870

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa converter o valor.

Com o `TryParse` além de converter, é possível verificar se houve sucesso na conversão, pois ele retorna um `bool`.

```
private void btn_Adicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    {
        if
            (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLogin.Text) &&
            !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSenha.Text) &&
            !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNivel.Text))

             if(!int.TryParse(txtNivel.Text, out int nivel))
             {
                  MessageBox.Show("o valor do nível não é númerico");
                  return;
             }

            Gravar(txtLogin.Text, txtSenha.Text, nivel, txtInfAdicinais.Text);

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Este recurso está disponível a partir do C#7, nas versões anteriores é necessário declarar a variável de saída fora do `TryParse`. Créditos [Marconcilio Souza](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/43340/marconcilio-souza)

**EDIT**

Se quiser saber mais sobre `TryParse` tem essa [ótima resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16203/88361) sobre o assunto, vale a pena ler.

Comment: lembre de mencionar a versão do C# para isso funcionar e do tratamento de erro caso não seja feito a conversão.

Comment: Problema resolvido muito obg

Comment: @FernandoRodrigues, se resolveu, marca a resposta como correta ;)

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza, a versão eu não saberia responder, se puder adicionar a resposta para agregar valor, ficaria grato.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31724198/2740371

Comment: Dou o +1 c/ o maior prazer, essa é uma das primeiras respostas que que ensina o certo, ainda que deve ter trocentas respostas iguais pelo site e a pergunta seja duplicata.